# Render number of bytes from user input in short notation (e.g. 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', etc)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to build component that reads the number of bytes from user input and translates that into short notation with suffixes 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', etc appended.

So, if the user inputs 3456 it turns that into 3kB, 32456128 is turned into 32MB and so on.

My first attempt on that was to use RegExp of the following form:

```
e.target.value.replace(/^(\d+)(\d{3})$/, (m,g0,g1) => g1 ? g0+'k' : m)
```

It sort of worked, but several issues I faced right away:
* it is hard to scale
* difficult to round to the nearest integer (3586 should turn into '4k', not '3k')

My component in simplified form:

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(''),
        onNumInput = e => { 
          const shortNum = e.target.value.replace(/^(\d+)(\d{3})$/, (m,g0,g1) => g1 ? g0+'k' : m)
          setNum(shortNum)
        }
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="number" onChange={onNumInput} />
      <div>{num}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

render (<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

How do I fix above issues to get desired functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to employ `Math` methods to achieve your goal:

```js
const { useState } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')

const App = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(''),
        onNumInput = ({target:{value}}) => { 
          if(!value.length) setNum('')
          else {
            const suffixes = ['', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB'],
                  {min, log, round, pow} = Math,
                  power = min(0|log(value)/log(1024), suffixes.length-1),
                  base = round(value/pow(1024,power)),
                  suffix = suffixes[power]          
            setNum(`${base}${suffix}`)
          }
        }
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="number" onChange={onNumInput} />
      {!!num.length && <div>{num}</div>}
    </div>
  )
}

render (
  <App />,
  rootNode
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```